# database table design dilemma, a lot of check boxes?

Tags: php, mysql, html, database-design, cakephp

I want to begin with Thank you, you guys have been good to me.

I will go straight to the question.

Having a table with over 400 columns, is that bad?

I have web forms that consists mainly of questions that require check box answers.
The total number of check boxes can run up to 400 if not more.

I actually modeled one of the forms, and put each check box in a column (took me hours to do).
Because of my unfamiliarity with database design, I did not feel like that was the right way to go.

So I read somewhere that some people use the serialize function, to store a group of check boxes as text in a column.

I just want to know it that would be the best way to store these check boxes.

Oh and some more info I will be using cakephp orm with these tables.

Thanks again in advance.

My database looks something like this

Table : Patients, Table : admitForm, Table : SomeOtherFOrm

each form table will have a PatientId

As i stated above i first attempted creating a table for each form, and then putting each check box in a column. That took me forever to do.

so i read some where serializing check boxes per question would be a good idea

So im asking would would be a good approach.

Comment: What are you wanting to store? The questions themselves, or user responses to the questions?

Comment: For the record, even those those appear to be checkboxes, if you read the context of each question and associated answers, it looks to be a radio button, in that you should only select one answer per question, vs multiple answers per question. For example, in the last question, I can't see multiple selections of 'Offered and declined' and 'None of the above' to be a valid response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

== Edit #3 ==
Updated ERD with ability to store free form answers, also linked patient_reponse_option to question_option_link table so a patients response will be saved with correct option context (we know which question the response is too). I will post a few queries soon.

[image]

== Edit #2 ==

Updated ERD with form data

[image]

== Edit #1 ==

The short answer to your question is no, 400 columns is not the right approach. As an alternative, check out the following schema:

[image]

== Original ==

According to your recent edit, you will want to incorporate a pivot table. A pivot table breaks up a M:M relationship between 'patients' and 'options', for example, many patients can have many options. For this to work, you don't need a table with 400 columns, you just need to incorporate the aforementioned pivot table.

Example schema:

```
// patient table
tableName: patient
id: int(11), autoincrement, unsigned, not null, primary key
name_first: varchar(100), not null
name_last: varshar(100), not null

// Options table
tableName: option
id: int(11), autoincrement, unsigned, not null, primary key
name: varchar(100), not null, unique key

// pivot table
tableName: patient_option_link
id: int(11), autoincrement, unsigned, not null, primary key
patient_id: Foreign key to patient (`id`) table
option_id: Foreign key to option (`id`) table
```

With this schema you can have any number of 'options' without having to add a new column to the patients table. Which, if you have a large number of rows, will crush your database if you ever have to run an `alter table add column` command.

I added an id to the pivot table, so if you ever need to handle individual rows, they will be easier to work with, vs having to know the patient_id and option_id.

Comment: I am not able to comprehend what you are saying, or i think you misunderstand part of my question. Each form can be broken down to questions. Each question, has a couple of checkboxs for example: How will you Pay ? select all that apply . from what i understand in your answer (thanks by the way ) just the check boxes are stored. How would i know which option belongs to which question ?

Comment: @mojotaker: So you are wanting to store the questions in your database, each question has multiple checkboxes?

Comment: Sorry didnt see your question ontime. Just the answers.

Comment: @mojotaker: Updated response.

Comment: so if i understand, i would be storeing the questions the options and the answers in the database ?

Comment: @mojotaker: This is the assumption. It was difficult to glean what you were after from the OP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5449/discussion-between-mojotaker-and-digital-precision)

Comment: Sorry 2 more things: yes some questions require multiple answers and how would i represent the options cause some questions require both multiple options and a text / int field

Comment: @mojotaker: Updated ERD to reflect ability to store free-form responses.

Answer (score 2):

For questions with multiple options, just add another table.

The question that nobody has asked you yet is do you need to do data mining or put the answers to these checkbox questions into a where clause in a query.  If you don't need to do any queries on the data that *look* at the data contained in these answers then you can simply serialize them up into a few fields.  You could even pack them into numbers.  (all who come after you will hate you if you pack the data though)

Here's my idea of a schema.

[image: The Database Schema Pictorial]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to respond. I also like your answer. And what if later in the future i want to data mine ("look at the data contained in these answers") ? would your approach be the best. and if so can you explain it futher. Thanks

Comment: Wow... visual SQL charts!?! You should automatically get 100 rep points just for putting so much work into this.

Comment: If you need to mine the data, you could issue a query like `select * from answer inner join question on question_id=answer_question_id inner join option on answer_option_id=option_id where question_form_id = 1 and question_id=1 and option_id = 1 and answer_value='1'`

Answer (score 1):

I think I would split this out into 3 tables. One table representing whatever entity is answering the questions. A second table containing the questions themselves. Finally, a third junction table that will be populated with the primary key of the first table and the id of the question from the second table whenever the entity from the first table selects the check box for that question.

Comment: Im already doing something similar to what you suggested. But a question could have multiple check boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Usually 400 columns means your data could be normalized better and broken into multiple tables. 400 columns might actually be appropriate, though, depending on the use case. An example where it might be appropriate is if you need these fields on every single query AND you need to filter records using these columns (ie: use them in your WHERE clause)... in that case the SQL JOINs will likely be more expensive than having a sparsely populated "wide" table.

If you never need to use SQL to filter out records based on these "checkboxes" (I'm guessing they are yes/no boolean/tinyint type values) then serializing is a valid approach. I would go this route if I needed to use the checkbox values most of time I query the table, but don't need to use them in a WHERE clause.

If you don't need these checkbox values, or only need a small subset of them, on a majority of requests to your table then its likely you should work on breaking your table into multiple tables. One approach is to have a table with the checkbox values (id, record_id, checkbox_name, checkbox_value) where `record_id` is the `id` of your primary table record. This implies a one-to-many relationship between your primary records and your checkbox values.

Comment: Thank you. I like option 2, My limited knowledge makes me think option 3 is over kill. One more question for you please if you dont mind, lets say i have 4 similar forms and they need to share data (say form A has some info form B needs, Instead of having the user fill all the questions in form B) will option 2 still be a good approach ?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the use case you are describing, but it sounds like serializing should work. You have the DB record with serialized answers from form A. When you present form B you unserialize the form A answers and use them to build/populate form B with whatever info you need from the form A answers. Then, when the user submits form B you can either unserialize your current answers, add the form B answers, and re-serialize the data with the combined answers, or have a separate column for answers from form A and answers from form B. Either approach should work.

Comment: Your welcome. An up vote or acceptance of my answer would be nice :-)

Comment: its Unfortunate, that i can only pick one answer, as most of these answers are correct and help towards the solution. Crap everytime i press enter is saves my comment. I was going to add i am still waiting a response from @tim-g

Comment: I wouldn't be offended if the answer with charts got accepted :-P